# list all timezone transitions for specified timespan

Tags: php, timezone

Yeah, I know there is `DateTimeZone::getTransitions()`. But I kind of confused with its output. What I would expect is the list like this:

```
2013-03-31 03:00:00 -> 2013-03-31 04:00:00
2013-10-27 03:00:00 -> 2013-10-27 02:00:00
```

What's more, I wonder why it returns information about `$timestamp_begin`. Generally, user won't pass transition timestamp for this parameter.

Comment: What aspect of the output are you confused about?

Comment: There is `time` in resulting array. It's supposedly the time when transition happens. And is probably `ts` printed in `UTC`. `offset` is probably resulting offset. But what was the value of previous offset then?

Comment: I guess you'd have to look at the previous array element?

Comment: @Pekka 웃 Please, review my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to help from Pekka 웃, I've come up with the following script:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Havana');
$transitions = (new DateTime)->getTimeZone()->getTransitions(
    strtotime('2013-01-01'),
    strtotime('2013-12-31'));
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
for ($i = 1; $i < count($transitions); $i++)
        printf("%s -> %s\n",
            strftime("%F %T",
                $transitions[$i]['ts'] + $transitions[$i - 1]['offset']),
            strftime("%F %T",
                $transitions[$i]['ts'] + $transitions[$i]['offset']));
```